# Calculating distance based on wifi signal strength

Tags: math

I am trying to get the current location with in a building using wifi signal strength. So first trying to get the distance then from that distance can get the x,y coodinates. I just have this idea but no mathematics logic for that. So need some help to achieve this.

Comment: This is, as some comments have indicated, a more suitable topic for a PhD than SO.  As it stands, it's way too ill-formed to be considered programming-related even by the widest interpretation seen here.

Comment: Why the anonymous downvote? Why couldn't this question be answered? I just answered it.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark This question can be answered in one simple sentence, see my answer. Yes, the answer points to a PhD thesis :)

Comment: No @Ali, you haven't answered the question, you've provided a link to something that might answer the question.  Your response reinforces my contention that this question is ill-suited to SO's format, it requires a PhD thesis to answer.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yes, you are right, there is no short *self-contained* answer.

Comment: If you are hoping for formulas that you can use as a black box, just giving a signal strenght to it and expecting an answer in meters then you are on the wrong track. What you want to do is notoriously difficult, people write PhD thesis on this subject. Read the chapter I linked.

Answer (score 2):

See **7.1 WiFi-assisted localisation** on page 141 in  [Pedestrian Localisation for Indoor Environment](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/www/people/ojw28) PhD thesis.

So it's possible, just hell of a lot more complicated than you expect... :(

Comment: Thanks Ali, Let me check the pdf related to the above link. And if u have any ideas then pls share.....

Comment: @MrunmayaPatro OK, I have added a link to a human readable document.

Comment: Thanks guys for Replying. I have one more doubt on converting Dbm into meter. How can I make this convertion ?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to consider:

- initial signal strength
- antenna gain
- antenna directionality
- reflections
- interference
- walls

Good luck with all that...

Comment: Thanks Alnitak, But Do u have any formulas to achieve the distance by implementing all these ?

Comment: Hmm, they must be laying around here somewhere.  Ah no, I remember - I need to do a PhD in maths and another in physics first...

Comment: ha ha ha. Let me see for other alternatives. Thanks for replying

Comment: @Alnitak This can be done, see my answer. It is just significantly more complicated than the OP expects.